# Why is my instance not saving for my search form?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, instance-variables, pry

I've got a search form that returns our products. However, if a user inputs a string that contains certain words (in this instance, 'color'), it returns far too many products.  I'm trying to remove the string 'color' from the query that is searched on the backend, but maintain the original query's string as @unfiltered_query so I can reference the @unfiltered_query on the front-end template.

```
if query.include? "color"
  @unfiltered_query = query
end
query.slice! "color"
values = query.split
binding.pry
```

It was not working, so I ran pry to see what was going on.  In the form, I searched "Red paint color".  When I call @unfiltered_query in pry, it outputs "Red paint", even though I create the method before .slice! is called?!

What am I missing?

Thank you!

p.s.  the HTML template that I'm using to reference the instance is:

```
<div class="search-input"><h2>
    <% if @unfiltered_query.present? %>
       <%= @unfiltered_query.titleize %>
    <% else %>
       <%= query.titlelize %>
    <% end %>
</h2></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try like this :

```
if query.include? "color"
  @unfiltered_query = query.dup
end
query.slice! "color"
values = query.split
binding.pry
```

This could be due to passing by reference.

Comment: Rather than copying the value of the `query` and assigning to `@unfiltered_query`, `@unfiltered_query` will be having a reference to `query`, so that if you change either one of them, it will be reflected in the other as well.

Comment: Oh man, now the @unfiltered_query isn't getting called on the front-end.  Do I need to do something to make it available to the front-end template?

Comment: `@unfiltered_query` is returning empty value.? Try with pry.

Comment: It's correct with pry...but the view template is saying there isn't an @unfiltered_query